# How to detect or remove noisy flickering patterns in a discrete space?

Tags: time-series, pattern-recognition

right now we are dealing with this problem with euristhics designed on the specific problem but I would like to approach this same problem with something smarter.

For example, imagine I have a sequence of the form [A,A,A,A,B,C,D,E,F,E,F,E,F,E,F, G]. Every point is paired with a timestamp. I would like to be able to detect the flickering between E and F and treat as if it was the same as the repeating pattern [A, A, A, A].  I expect the flickering between E and F to have always the same temporal structure but I would like to have some control on the threshold to cut out false positives.

I believe that with time series analysis this should be easy but it's a subject I barely know of and I would love some pointers to the right approach to such a problem.

Thanks

Comment: Do you only want to detect a regular pattern like "EFEFEFEF", or do you also want to be able to detect irregular patterns like: "EFEEFEFEFFEF" with some variation

Comment: Yes also the second is a possible scenario.

Comment: And do you also want to be able to detect E and F seperately? So for example: "EFEFEFAAAABBBBBEEEEECCCCFFFFF"

Comment: Actually I believe it's enough to detect the time frame where I have this "EFEFEFEEF" patterns. It's basically data cleaning for a wider pipeline, so just knowning that a timeframe is "not good" is enough for us right now.